# How do plot multiple filtered subsets of an image collection on one chart in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have created a MWE to try to describe my problem. I would like a time series plot of surface temperature for a given region by Month, with two lines: one for 2019 and one for 2020. In the code below, I read in a dataset of monthly surface temperatures, select the dates and band that I am interested in, and then plot a chart that averages over an arbitrary region I have defined. This works well for displaying only 2019, but I am not sure how to display 2020 as a separate line.

```
// Read in dataset of monthly surface temperatures
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY");

// Subset the data to get only 2019 and only mean temperature
var subset1 = dataset
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01','2019-12-31'))
                .select(['mean_2m_air_temperature']);
                
var subset2 = dataset
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01','2020-12-31'))
                .select(['mean_2m_air_temperature']);                
                

// Define a region to average over
var poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-115, 35], [-115, 45], [-95, 45], [-95, 35], [-115, 35]]]);

// Create the time series that shows up in console
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
              imageCollection: subset1,
              region: poly,
              reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
              scale: 500, // Not sure what this means yet
              xProperty: 'month'})
              .setSeriesNames(['2019'])
              .setOptions({
                hAxis:{'title':'Month'},
                vAxis:{'title':'Temperature (K)'}
              });
print(chart)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ui.Chart.feature.groups()` to get multiple series by a property. That do require you to convert your image collection to a feature collection of means. Here's one approach that makes it easy to include additional years by just changing the date range (note the `endDate` is exclusive, before you missed the last day of the year):

```
var startDate = '2019-01-01'
var endDate = '2021-01-01'

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY")
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)

// Define a region to average over
var poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-115, 35], [-115, 45], [-95, 45], [-95, 35], [-115, 35]]])
  
var features = dataset.map(function(image) {
  var mean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    geometry: poly, 
    scale: 500,
    bestEffort: true,
    maxPixels: 1e6
  }).get('mean_2m_air_temperature')
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    mean: mean, 
    year: image.date().get('year'),
    month: image.get('month')
  })
})

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
  features: features, 
  xProperty: 'month', 
  yProperty: 'mean', 
  seriesProperty: 'year'
}).setOptions({
  hAxis:{'title':'Month'},
  vAxis:{'title':'Temperature (K)'}
})
print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ec79d2c5954715391acce51432f3bbc1

You were uncertain how the `scale` property worked. [This](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/scale) should explain it.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! This is great and is a perfect and flexible answer for me. I also appreciate the link for `scale`!